# how show the title value for an input when it gets the focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have

```
<input type="text"
       name="name"
       id="name" 
       placeholder="your name" 
       title="only words" 
       value=""/>
```

If the user puts/moves the cursor over the textfield *without do click* **then** the `title`'s message appears. (It is expected). The problem is, is needed wait 1 or 2 seconds to see that message.

Therefore: I want show that message when the user gives the focus in the textfield too. Activate the event.

I have the following:

```
$("form#idform input[type=text]").focus(function() {
    //what to do?
});

$("form#idform input[type=text]").blur(function() {
    //what to do?
});
```

What code should go in `what to do?` respectively for each event?.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to write your own tooltip functionality to do this, or use an existing plugin. Why not just put that information in the `placeholder` attribute though? It's what it's designed for

Comment: Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/usfrfdje/156/

Comment: `placeholder` and `title` are very similar, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use qtip2.

Inlcude:

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.js

http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.css

Text Field:

```
<input type="text" title="My tooltip text1" />
```

Tooltip Initialize:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[title]').qtip();    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usfrfdje/156/)

For the audience, the following is the expected requirement, it is a complement from above:

```
$('input[title]').qtip({
    content: $(':focus').prop('title'),
    show: 'focus',
    hide: 'blur'
});
```

Comment: Even when your solution makes able to see the `title` quickly, when the user enters or gives focus to the field, it does not appear (the title message)

Answer (score -1):

title -> tooltip will appear when mouse over.  Yo can acces thi attribute in javascript:

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log(title);
  });
```

But for your question, yes you must write your own tooltip.

Comment: The goal is show the `message` in the same field, not through the `console`

Comment: in my code I just show how to pick up title attribute.  I use console for example only.

Comment: A final user sees directly the `form`, not the `Web Console`

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    console.log(title);
  });
```

code not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Answering the question with a couple lines of code followed by "code not work" is not helpful and confusing.